# Как отправив от клиента из браузера символ двойной кавычки, сохранить его в базе postgresql и вернуть обратно на клиента, отобразив в браузере?

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

Не получается сохранить в таблице postgresql символ *двойной кавычки* ".
Сохраняю в поле с типом данных *text*.
Отправляю от клиента в браузере аяксом, вношу в базу :

```
"INSERT INTO tbl (input) VALUES ('".$d['0']."') RETURNING id_t;"
```

и сразу по id_t возвращаю обратно на клиента в браузер.

---

Например, обработав так на клиенте символы *одинарной кавычки* и *&* :

```
   var info = info.replace(/'/g,"''");
   var info = info.replace(/&/g,"%26");
```

я их обратно на клиенте получаю и нормально отображаю через .innerHTML

---

С двойной кавычкой делаю так :

```
var info = info.replace(/\"/g,'&quot');
ну и другие варианты пробовал, но не сохраняет в базе и, соответственно,
не выводит обратно в браузер.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно делать. Спасибо.

---

update_1 (привожу код php) :

```
$data=$_POST['text'];
$d = json_decode($data, true);

$in1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl (input) VALUES (:f) RETURNING id_t;");
$in1->bindParam(':f', $d['0']);
$in1->execute();
$rid = $in1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);


$se1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT input FROM tbl WHERE id_t = $rid[0];");
$se1->execute();
$rw = $se1->fetch();

echo '{"0":"'.$rw['0'].'"}';
```

Comment: Надо использовать компиляцию запроса ("prepare") и привязку параметров ("bind") к скомпилированному запросу. Так надо делать всегда и везде и с любой БД. Это стандарт. Подставлять строки в SQL средствами скрипта - только в крайнем случае, когда bind не работает.

Comment: Через /prepare/ и делал, - здесь не привёл, чтобы не нагромождать.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, покажите, пожалуйста, как правильно .. думаю надо эту двойную кавычку как-то экранировать, чтобы работала строка запроса, но никак не могу осилить.

Comment: С prepare/bind при вставке в таблицу ничего экранировать не нужно, это точно, проблема где-то в другом месте. При выводе в html нужно заменить на `&quot;`. У вас запрос GET или POST?

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, POST

Comment: `var info = info.replace(/\"/g,'&quot');` - точку с запятой забыли, кстати.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, &quot; - пробовал так-же, спасибо, привёл код php в теле вопроса ..

Comment: а вы просто консольным клиентом (`psql` он вроде называется) можете в базу зайти и посмотреть, что там сохранилось?

Comment: я pgAdmin _ом смотрю, не любит postgresql двойные кавычки, - не вставляет их ..

Comment: а через pgAdmin можете руками прям запросом insert вставить?

Comment: Да, так вставляет : INSERT INTO tbl (input) VALUES ('"');

Comment: Вношу в инпут на клиенте двойную кавычку (") , на сервере php заворачиваю запрос обратно на клиента и копирую из алерта : INSERT INTO tbl (input) VALUES (''); Т.е. тут уже не двойная, а две одинарные - пусто, поэтому лажа. Не пойму почему идёт подмена.